# Nikon 16-85 VR focus noise problem?

Tags: lens, nikon, focus, sound

My 16-85 VR is doing some weird noise during focus, manual or auto. It's like an hiss. I asked in a local shop and they said it can be some microdust inside the lens. But I'm a little worried it can be the beginning of a bigger problem. The lens is no more in warranty so, what can I do? What do you think guys?

I'll attach a video so you can listen to the noise. Sorry for the crappy quality. http://it.tinypic.com/player.php?v=2q0nj9c&s=8

Comment: My personal thoughts, if it isn't broken yet and it isn't in warranty, don't fix it.  If it is small amounts of dust, then opening it up may let even more dust in that you are able to clean out.  You could always send the lens in for a cleaning, but there is no guarantee that would fix it.

Comment: I can't listen to the video, I can only see a page with dozen of ads. Are you sure the noise is not a VR noise?

Answer (score 1):

> You could always send the lens in for a cleaning, but there is no guarantee that would fix it

From [AJ Henderson](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48829/nikon-16-85-vr-focus-noise-problem/52776#comment83328_48829)

I'd vote for a visit to a repair shop, a "[CLA](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15613/what-is-cla-service)" might be the right choice, or not.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, the best thing to do is to find out what causes the noise. When it comes to stabilized lenses, it's very common to hear `weird noise`.

To rule this out, turn VR off and listen. If the noise is still present, you should probably send the lens to the service center. If the noise disappeared, it's perfectly normal and don't worry about it.