# What kind of adapter do I need to put an Olympus OM lens on my Canon T3?

Tags: lens-adapter, olympus, canon-1100d

I have a Canon EOS Rebel T3/1100D and want to use an old lens. What kind of adapter should I use for an [Olympus Zuiko AUTO-Zoom 75-100mm f/4.0 lens](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/olympusom1n2/shared/zuiko/htmls/75150mm.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an Olympus OM mount lens and the T3 uses the Canon EOS mount, so **you need an OM -> EOS adapter ring**. You will want to make sure [the ring has a stop-down pin on it](https://www.flickr.com/photos/inkista/2787406017) to keep the DoF preview lever on the lens depressed, so the lens will stop down as you adjust the aperture ring.

Be aware that you will *not* have aperture control from the camera (you have to adjust aperture with the lens ring), you have to use stop-down metering, there's no autofocus, and you'll be limited to the M or Av shooting modes on the camera because the camera can't control the aperture of the lens.  In addition, none of the lens EXIF information will be transmitted, unless you get a chipped adapter ring.

I'd also suggest finding a reputable repair person and budgeting for a [CLA](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15613/what-is-cla-service), depending on the condition of the lens you've got.

See also: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)