# SLR light meter won't turn off and inaccurate

Tags: film, slr, maintenance

I had my ricoh xr500 CLA'd (i.e. sent to service) a few days ago. I noticed the light meter no longer shuts off and it does not display accurate measurements. Before I had it CLA'd the meter is working fine, the lever also turns off the meter when not in use. Should I open the bottom plate and check?

Comment: Maybe you should contact the party who you paid to do the CLA and ask them?

Comment: I did but I don't think they will cover the payment even if it didn't happen on my end. I'm thinking of opening the bottom plate to check. What can you recommend?

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to recommend that you open the bottom plate of a camera you are new to tinkering with, in case you break something permanently. I had a CLA done once, and the camera came back with unfixed problems. I sent it back and it was fixed properly. I recommend you do the same.

Comment: Obviously I have no clue here, but what does "CLA" mean?

Comment: @PeterM Clean, lubricate, adjust. See: [What is CLA service?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/15613/11924)

Comment: OP - what does your service contract state? Seems that you paid for services which have not yet been rendered, if the camera came back worse than before. The service should be obligated to fix the camera or at minimum refund your contract.

Comment: @PeterM, I don't support jargon for jargon's sake, but CLA is a pretty common photographic acronym. Maybe not quite as common as, say, SLR, but it's not unusual to use it and just assume others are familiar.

Comment: @osullic The problem with TLAs such as CLA is that it is an assumption that it *is* widely known.  That would be a reasonable assumption if you knew the experience level of your audience, but these forums are open to everyone of all levels of  experience, so there will always be a segment of the audience that won't know your pet TLA.

Comment: @PeterM Based on a sampling of one (me), CLA is much more common and understood than TLA, whatever that means. So what's a TLA?

Comment: CLA -> Clean, Lubricate, Adjust (Sent to service)
TLA -> Three letter acronym

Comment: @MichaelC Kai let the cat out of the bag :(  For me TLA is very widely known, so I didn't feel a need to define it, and why should I?  After all it's well known!  Alaska Man got the point/sarcasm/joke.

Comment: @PeterM I think you are replying tongue-in-cheek, and you even have somewhat of a point. But we cannot go around assuming nobody knows anything. CLA is common in the photography world, and as has been pointed out to you earlier, if you don't know what a CLA is, we even have a Q&A about that too. So, if _you_ don't know the jargon, search; don't complain ;-)

Comment: @PeterM I would beg to differ. TLA is not widely known here. We have a question with CLA in the title and many answers with CLA in the answers. They all show in a search. "TLA", on the other hand, appears used in this way (without explanation) in one answer from a decade ago. P.S. Where is Alaska Man's comment?

Answer (score 1):

The [manual for the XR500](https://www.cameramanuals.org/ricoh_pdf/ricoh_xr500_auto.pdf) does not indicate that there is a way to turn the light meter off. Except by removing the batteries.

Comment: You can turn it off by pushing the lever. I always turn it off when not in use